# Need the intersection of two path-connected subspaces be path-connected for their union to be path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

This is problem 1.20 in An Introduction to Algebraic Topology by Rotman.

Let $A$ and $B$ be path-connected subspaces of a space $X$. If $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$ is path-connected, then $A \cup B$ is path-connected.

Informal proof: Since $A$, $B$, and $A \cap B$ are path-connected, let's restrict our attention to points $a \in A \setminus B$ and $b \in B \setminus A$. If $c \in A \cap B$, there is a path $a \to c$ and a path $c \to b$. Compose these two paths to yield a path $a \to b$.

**Question**: I am hoping for clarification on the requirement that $A \cap B$ be path-connected, since it doesn't seem necessary. Does it just make the proof easier?

Suppose we take $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$, let $A = \{e^{2\pi i t} \, | \, t \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}] \}$ and $B = \{e^{2\pi i t} \, | \, t \in [0,\frac{3}{8}] \cup [\frac{5}{8}, 1]\}$ (in other words, two semi-circular subsets that overlap a bit at their ends). The intersection of these subspaces is nonempty and consists of two disjoint open sets, so is not connected and therefore not path-connected, yet $A \cup B = S^1$ is path-connected.

What is an example of two path-connected subspaces with nonempty, non-path-connected intersection such that their union is not path-connected?

Comment: Yes the path connectedness of $A \cap B$ is unnecessary. As long as $A$ and $B$ has a point in common, $A \cup B$ will be path connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessary. Your informal proof is correct. See Rotman's Theorem 1.15.

Pick $c \in A  \cap B$. Then each $a \in A$ satisfies $a \sim c$ and each $b \in B$ satisfies $b \sim c$, thus each $x \in X$ satisfies $x \sim c$. Since $\sim $ is transitive, any two points $x, y \in X$ satisfy $x \sim y$.